# To get time before the application crash

Tags: java, oracle, crash

I'm using an application which is java / oracle based. My need is "**I want to store the time in a event logger table before the application crash**".

Comment: First you'd need to define "crash". If it's a full-on `hs_err*`-producing JVM crash, then you're probably out of luck (unless you have a watchdog). If it's just "some important thread dies due to an uncaught exception", then read up on "uncaught exception handlers".

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to find the point where your application crashes. Then make sure your log happens at some point before that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with unplanned crashed is that we don't know when the come. You should make your logging crash proof, in such a way that your logs are not rolled back during the crash. For this is a simple solution, use an autonomous transaction. See a nice article by Tim [Autonomous Transactions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/AutonomousTransactions.php)